# Route [categories.update1] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\categories\create.blade.php)

Tags: java, php, laravel

I am trying to upadate my edited value but when i am clicking edit button then showing this error.

**Here is my code:**

```
<form action="{{ isset($category) ? route('categories.update'. 
$category->id):route('categories.store')}}" method="POST">
@csrf
    <div class="form-group mx-3">
        <label for="name" >Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" value=" {{isset($category)? 
         $category->name:''}} ">
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-3">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Add category</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: For update you are using put request or post??

Comment: Don't concatenate the value to the route name. _If_ you need to do it: `route('categories.update').$category->id`. Better use Localhousee's answer

Comment: How are `css` or `java` related? Don't tag-spam

Comment: I want to use PUT request but when i wrote {{ isset($category) ? route('categories.update'. 
$category->id) this showing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have syntax error

`route('categories.update'. $category->id)`

to

`route('categories.update',$category->id)`

remove `.` and use `,`

you put `.` which mean concat that's why your getting
`categories.update1] not defined.` this error you can se `1` id is concat with `categories.update`

Answer (score 3):

Fix your route name, dont concat it, wrap it to array instead

```
route('categories.update', ['category' => $category->id]) : route('categories.store')
```